# How to catch a ColdFusion CFHTTP timeout exception?

Tags: coldfusion, try-catch, cfml, coldfusion-11, timeoutexception

I have a page where I make a remote request to an external API. I sometimes get request timeouts when making the request, so, my plan to set a timeout in the CFHTTP tag that is lower than my default requesttimeout setting and catch it. However, I can't get my CFTRY/CFCATCH to catch it. Here is my pseudo code:

```
private void function makeRequest(){
        cfhttp(
            url="https://api.somesite.com/",
            method="POST",
            timeout="1",
            throwonerror="true",
            result="LOCAL.ApiHttpResult"
            ) {
        ...
        }
}

public void function tryRequest() {
    try {
        makeRequest();
    }
    catch(coldfusion.runtime.RequestTimeoutException e) {
        abort;
    }
}
```

I get the same result out of CFSCRIPT:

```
<cffunction access="public" returntype="void" name="tryRequest">
    <cftry>
        <cfscript>
            makeRequest();
        </cfscript>
    <cfcatch type="coldfusion.runtime.RequestTimeoutException">
        <cfabort />
    </cfcatch>
</cffunction>
```

Is there something special about the CFHTTP timing out that makes this impossible to catch programmatically? Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just misspelled the exception type: It's coldfusion.runtime.RequestTim**ed**OutException (`coldfusion.runtime.RequestTimedOutException`).

But there's another way to do this without exception handling. Just do a regular cfhttp, but don't specify the `throwOnError` attribute (or keep it `false`). This will still return a response struct after the request has timed out. It will be populated with status code `408 Request Time-out`. You can access it like this:

```
if (left(LOCAL.ApiHttpResult.Statuscode, 3) eq "408") {
    writeOutput("HTTP request timed out");
} else {
    writeOutput("HTTP request successful with status: #LOCAL.ApiHttpResult.Statuscode#");
}
```

Comment: Oh cool. I’m gonna try this today! Hoping to be able to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment, but this is way too long. Just do a dump off whatever exception is happening. Then filter on the specific exception

```
public void function tryRequest() {
    try {
        makeRequest();
    }
    catch(any e) {
        writedump(e);
        // then find the details on the specific exception type
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized I could do this but it feels kludgy to do a string search.  This may be my only option, though.